# meet exc_bad_access errror when operating on c-style string

Tags: c++, c, string, exc-bad-access

I'm solving a problem that "replace all spaces in a string with ‘%20’." and I want to operate on the original string instead of create a new string. Here is my code:

```
void replaceSpaces(char* s, int len) {

    int spaceCnt = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if(s[i] == ' '){
            ++spaceCnt;
        }
    }

    int newlen = len + 2 * spaceCnt;

    s[newlen] = '\0';

    for(int i = len - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if(s[i] == ' ') {
            s[newlen - 1] = '0';
            s[newlen - 2] = '2';
            s[newlen - 3] = '%';
            newlen -= 3;
        } else {
            s[newlen - 1] = s[i];
            --newlen;
        }
    }
}
```

And I have an "thread: exc_bad_access" error in the line `s[newlen] = '\0';`. I know it's dangerous to operate c-stye string in this way but I don't know how to modify it...

Any explanations or suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you add the calling code or even better a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? Are you passing a string literal?

Comment: This is just asking for a buffer overrun unless you are sure than s is at least (3 * len) + 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the original buffer is not long enough to contain the string with replacements, you are accessing memory out of bounds. When you determine the new size, you could do a [realloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/realloc)  call to reallocate a suffiecient buffer with the size `newlen` like `*s = realloc(*s, newsize)`. The only issue is that you need to change the paramter from `char* s` to `char** s` so that if `realloc` moves the memory to another block you update the pointer. And of course, this will work with strings allocated on heap, not local stack strings, since you can't reallocate that.